# how to send formatted email from ajax through mvc controller

Tags: ajax

I am using a jquery dialog box to create an email that will be sent to multiple addresses.  I collect the Subject and Body in the dialog box and send those values along with an array of customerIDs through ajax to my mvc4 controller and it then sends out the mail to each address.  I have no problems with the code or sending the emails, however I would like to know if there is a way to format the email body while I am creating it?

I use a textarea tag to create my body:

```
<textarea id="emailBody" class="inputText" rows="5" cols="60" wrap="hard" >  </textarea>
```

Preferably I would like to be able to format the body within the textarea tag so that I have flexibility each time I use the feature.  However if not, then I will look at whatever approach is available.

Here is a piece of my javascript from my send button:

```
"Send Emails": function () {
                        $(".groupCheckbox:checked").each(function () {
                            var thisCust = ($(this).val());
                            var groupItem = { ID: thisCust };
                            groupEmails.push(groupItem);
                        });
                        sendGroupEmails = groupEmails;
                        sendGroupEmails = JSON.stringify({ 'sendGroupEmails': sendGroupEmails, Subject: $('#emailSubject').val(), Body: $('#emailBody').val() });
                        $.ajax(
                        {
                            contentType: 'application/json; charset=utf-8',
                            dataType: 'json',
                            type: 'POST',
                            url: '@Url.Action("SendGroupEmail", "General")',
                            data: sendGroupEmails,
                            cache: false,
```

and my controller method:

```
    [HttpPost]
    public JsonResult SendGroupEmail(Customer[] sendGroupEmails, string Subject, string Body)
    {
        string EmailFrom = "------------";
        string Comment = Subject + " - Sent to client";
        int success = 1;
            foreach (var item in sendGroupEmails)
            {
                try
                {
                Customer customer = dataService.CustomerGet(item.ID);
                string EmailTo = customer.Email;
                Utilities utils = new Utilities();
                utils.SendEmail(EmailFrom, EmailTo, Subject, Body);
                }
                catch { success = 0; };
        }
        return this.Json(success);
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

"I would like to know if there is a way to format the email body while I am creating it?"

Yes, use a WYSIWYG editor, not a `textarea`.

Comment: What type of tag are you suggesting that I use.  I have tried creating the text in Word and copying it over, but I need to insert it into some tag in order to move the value as described above.

Comment: MS Word make crappy, bloated HTML with embedded crap that's going to break. Never use it. Try this instead: http://jhollingworth.github.io/bootstrap-wysihtml5/